# 通信（HTTPリクエスト）のキャンセルと放置はどちらが良いか

Tags: network, http, 非同期

例えば、Google サジェストなど文字を入力する度サーバーと通信(HTTPリクエスト)しますが
通信(HTTPリクエスト)は非同期で行われてる為、前回のレスポンスが返ってきてない状態で新たにリクエストを行います。

この時、戻ってきてないリクエストはもう不要ですがabortした方が良いでしょうか？
それとも、放置でかまわないでしょうか？

クライアント側は、どちらの実装が良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

例で挙げていらっしゃるものですと、結局実装次第になるかと思います。
サーバと通信するタイミングは、おそらくKey関連イベントで即時にやっているわけではなく、1秒単位等でやっていると思います（そうでなければ無駄な負荷が多すぎるので）
また、サーバ側でも受け取ったデータの処理は1秒単位等で丸めてやっていると思うので、放置でもキャンセルでも大差ありません。

ただ、サーバ側の処理が一瞬で終わるようなものに限定し、且つあえて仰る様な実装を行う場合には、「２」の放置がより良いと思います。
理由としては、HTTPのAPI通信で最も重い処理は、HTTPリクエスト自体の処理なので、キャンセルリクエストを送ることでより処理負荷が高くなってしまう場合の方が多いはずだからです。

Comment: 「キャンセルリクエストを送る」という意味がよく分かりません。HTTPにそんな機能ありましたっけ。

Comment: 「通信をキャンセルする。」というのが、キャンセル用のAPIを用意するという意味だと思っておりましたが、取り違えていたようでしたらすいません。

クライアント（ブラウザ）側で、レスポンスが来る前に待ち状態を止めるという事でしょうか？
abort()等で通信を切るのは多少効果があると思いますが、それだけだとサーバ側の処理は止まらないので、負荷軽減にさほど寄与する訳ではないはずです。
また、「通信をキャンセルする。」をしっかり行う場合、キャンセル用APIを用意し、サーバ側処理のキャンセル＋abort()等でクライアント側の待ちもキャンセルする形になるかと思います。

Comment: 「通信するタイミングは…1秒単位」「サーバ側…の処理は1秒単位」というのはそういう実装もあるでしょうが一般的に言える話ではありません。すくなくともGoogle Suggestはそのような動作はしません

Comment: 1秒単位で云々というのは、あくまで負荷軽減策の一例です。また、こういった分野では何かしらの形で一時キャッシュを持つのが一般的です。
Google Suggestは一応ざっくり確認してみたところ、メモリかcookieか何かで持っている検索文字列に合致しない文字列になった際に、リクエストを送っている様です。
hiro様の質問を見るに、Google サジェストは一例として挙げられているのだと思っておりましたが、Google サジェストを実現する前提のお話でしょうか？
これは、Googleが長年研究を続けてきた分野ですので、おそらく利用しているWebサーバソフトのレベルから独自のもので、もっと言えば物理インフラ、OS自体にも相当なカスタマイズが加わっているはずです。
ですので、Googleと同じリクエスト方法で実現しようとするのは、実はあまり現実的でない事を申し添えておきます。
（一応ですが、当方元銀行系インフラSE、現在大規模分散システムの開発者です。）

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ありません。
クライアントからサーバーにHTTPリクエストを投げて、不要なリクエストはabortした方がクライアント側は良いのか不明だったためご質問させて頂きました。

拝見させて頂いた限りでは、abortではサーバー側には余りメリットもなく、
記載は無いですがクライアントにも対してメリットが無さそうだと感じました。

また、サーバー側が重い処理をするようなものであれば、abortではなくキャンセルリクエストを出すような実装が望ましいと言う事もわかりました。

ご回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

APIの一般論としては、リクエストをきちんと完結させたり不要なリクエストをキャンセルすることを提供側が求めているのであれば、キャンセルする仕組みがあるはずです。一方で、キャンセルする仕組みが無ければそもそも利用者にはどうしようもありません。

単純なリクエスト/レスポンスを繰り返すweb APIはまず間違いなく後者でしょうが、重い処理をする(レスポンスに時間がかかる)処理とか、状態を持っているものであればキャンセルする仕組みがある場合もあります。

ということで、コスト云々よりもまずはAPIの仕様を確認すべきです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。 クライアントからサーバーにHTTPリクエストを投げて、不要なリクエストはabortした方がクライアント側は良いのか不明だったためご質問させて頂きました。abortは余り意味がなさそうですね、勉強になりましたありがとうございます。